# Sandbox Edge/Apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, uac

It's my understanding that Edge [is an app](https://windowsforum.com/threads/apps-vs-programs.212888/), not a [program](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp) in Windows 10.  Removing it is difficult, but [can be done](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10).  That's good, and I can easily find help on that matter.

However, what if I wanted to just remove the tendrils of Edge throughout the OS and still have access to it for legacy/compatibility reasons?  Much the same way even a staunch Firefox user still has IE available for those websites that require it.  Is there a way to downgrade it to a regular app or program?  Maybe with 3rd party software?

Also, if you completely disable UAC (not just drop the slider all the way down), Edge, and all the rest of the apps, [will not run](https://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/3822-disable-uac.html).  Or at least that's what [people say](https://superuser.com/questions/1013702/completely-disable-uac-in-windows-10).

Is there a middle ground where I can have a Windows OS that runs Windows software, but that I still control?  Maybe a button like another user said "I know wtf I'm doing, let me do it!"

Reasons why I want to sandbox Edge: I want to disable UAC, Edge is [considered a PDF viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/1022063/windows-10-default-programs-keep-changing/1155421#1155421), compatibility, it's [more secure than IE](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/windows-10-sharpens-browser-security-with-microsoft-edge/), etc.

I'm thinking I may need to just have a plain W10 VM side by side with my usual OS.

**P.S.**

OK, I get that the new apps are sandboxed by by design; I guess I meant more of a flower pot.  Where I would uproot an existing app (Edge), and then transplant it into it's own "flower pot" so that it was still usable and had everything it needed, even in a system where it could otherwise not live (UAC disabled).  It sounds like that's not possible though.  That would probably require a massive OS overhaul.  At that point, it's just time to go to Linux I guess.

Comment: You have cooked up a very weird definition for "program" and "app"! "Program" and "app" refer to the same thing, except "program" is outdated since 2010. You are looking for "UWP app" vs. "Desktop app". Edge is an unconventional UWP app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to downgrade it to a regular app or program?

In order to convert Edge to be traditional Win32 desktop application, and it is indeed a *Universal Windows Platform application (UWP)*, you would need the source code to it.  Since the source code to Edge, has not been published, you will be unable to convert.  **If you want the ability to launch UWP applications then UAC must be set to at least the default setting.**

> Also, if you completely disable UAC (not just drop the slider all the
>   way down), Edge, and all the rest of the apps, will not run. Or at
>   least that's what people say.

*Universal Windows Platform applications* were designed to only function if UAC was set to the required minimum setting.  If you disable UAC, you have set UAC at a setting below, the required minimum UAC setting.

> Reasons why I want to sandbox Edge: I want to disable UAC, Edge is
>   considered a PDF viewer, compatibility, it's more secure than IE, etc.

*Universal Windows Platform* applications are already sandboxed.  That is the major benefit of *Universal Windows Platform* applications, they can only access certain locations on your system, unlike traditional desktop applications which can access any location the user which launched them can access.

> However, what if I wanted to just remove the tendrils of Edge
>   throughout the OS and still have access to it for legacy/compatibility
>   reasons?

You have been able to completely remove Internet Explorer since at least IE9.  While difficult, you can remove Edge, and any of the *Universal Windows Platform* applications that are installed by default.

> I'm thinking I may need to just have a plain W10 VM side by side with
>   my usual OS.

You could also just use the current versions of Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB (1511,1607) which by default does not have Edge installed.

> Edge is considered a PDF viewer, compatibility, it's more secure than
>   IE, etc.

If you install a different application to view PDF files you can set that as the default application.  This makes it so Edge, even if you click on a link to a PDF, itself will not be the application that displays the contents of the PDF.

> it's my understanding that Edge is an app, not a program in Windows 10

In reality there is no different between the term `App` and `Program` both are applications which are launched by the user.  The term `App` became popular with Android and iOS due to their "**App**lication Stores" ( i.e. Apple **App Store** )

Comment: @FleetCommand - The ability to get a license to Enterprise LTSB does not change the fact, using it, would get rid of Edge by default.

Comment: I like your note about "app". The word "application" is a result of failed attempt to categorize programs into two categories of _application_ and _utility_. Since this categorization failed, people kept using "application" to mean "program". (e.g. an _application developer_ might really develop any kind of application.) "App" is the clipped form of "application" and officially means "program".

Comment: You **say** that you can make another application a default; a new feature in that regard is highly problematic. There is no end to people complaining about how default applications are overridden.  I have found 3 different programs to address the issue, & there are a plethora of Q&A here and articles and threads elsewhere discussing the issue. File Association Fixer http://www.thewindowsclub.com/file-association-fixer-2-windows-10-8-7 .  Stop resetting my Apps http://www.carifred.com/stop_resetting_my_apps/ .  File Types Manager http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Comment: @DanWhaley Defaults would only be reset when feature updates are installed.   I have used Windows 10 since day 1, my defaults have reset twice Nov 15 and July 16.